# Status bar blinked when hide and show status bar

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

In iOS 11, I have a problem with status bar show/hidden.
But it just happens when I change color status bar

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

I have two screens. Screen 1 shows black status bar, screen 2 hides black status bar. When back to screen 1, status bar will blink.

I upload my sample to Github:
https://github.com/phungtai/StatusBar.git

Note:
- Only iOS 11.xx.xx
- happening when change color status bar, keep default will not happening.
https://media.giphy.com/media/l3dj1EXWwic3oP6KY/giphy.gif

Comment: Link gif: https://media.giphy.com/media/l3dj1EXWwic3oP6KY/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

I change status bar color with new solution and resolved bug

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIView()

// In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AppDelegate

statusBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        window?.rootViewController?.view.insertSubview(statusBar, aboveSubview: statusBar)
```